# Text boxes with automatic counting

Tags: inkscape, automation

I need to build a grid with a1 a2 a3 ... b1 b2 b3 ... and so on, is there a way to automatically generate the necessary blocks without editing the text on each manually?

Comment: Can you show a small sample? Since SVG is an editable XML format, you can easily script it. Draw your example by hand, look at it in the XML-viewer, generate such code with a script, paste it into your file at the right level.